# Convert Mascot mztab file format to XML

Tags: proteomics

Cross-posted [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/9519307/)

I would like to convert MASCOT mztab file to XML format. I have been looking for converters and I came across PRIDE Converter but this is no longer available for download from here https://github.com/PRIDE-Toolsuite/pride-converter-2.

Could someone please suggest alternate converters, if available?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of converters to be found at http://www.pastelbioscience.co.uk/resources/databases.html , although not sure that the one you are looking for is among them. May also be better to ask this question on twitter. There is a large #proteomics community that are very helpful and usually come up with an answer :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).